# How to bring apache2 default web page im my browser with Dockerfile using jenkins

Tags: jenkins, docker, apache2, dockerfile

Apache2 got installed, but unable to load on server.
I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM myimage:latest
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apache2
ENV APACHE_RUN_USER www-data
ENV APACHE_RUN_GROUP www-data
ENV APACHE_LOG_DIR /var/log/apache2
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["usr/sbin/apache2ctl","-D","FOREGROUND"]
```

And i use the following command to build from jenkins:

```
sudo docker build -t apachecontainer -f /var/lib/jenkins/docker/Dockerfile /var/lib/jenkins
```

My build was successful. Problem is, not getting in browser.

Comment: Did you run the container, or stop after building it?

Comment: I didn't done anything..is there anything to do..? 'myimage' was loaded from .tar file ..

Comment: BMitch... I want to automate all the things using jenkins...please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you build the image, you create an immutable configuration that can be later run.

When you run a container, you load that image with the layered file system and any settings configured in the Dockerfile, and launch the process. So you need to do this second step still:

```
sudo docker run -p 80:80 apachecontainer
```

This will also bind the host's port 80 to the container's port 80.

Comment: Thanks.. So if i want to load this image on an machine using puppet, i also want execute this command...?

Comment: Yes, you would need this as part of your configuration management tool if you don't have some other orchestration tool managing containers for you. If you expect it to run after a reboot or crash, be sure to add a `--restart=always` to the run command.